# Read specific messages in android

Tags: android

> I want to read all specific messages and display it in listview , based on the picture below I want to display in listview ,those messages containing word "Notifier" , I have tried the code below but its not working

[image]

```
  public void reads() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();


    String notify = "Notifier";
    String sms1 = "body='"+ notify + "'";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "body" }, sms1, null,   null);

    System.out.println ( cursor.getCount() );

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String strbody = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("body") );
        System.out.println ( strbody );
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strbody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need is learn about String and String Regex.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/. [Have a look in this link].

And simple try to filter your string. With str.contains("your desired string" ). In your code just change the line with  if ( str.contains ("Notifier"))  arrayAdapter.add(str).

Comment: I have updated my code above, When I use "address='123456789'" it works  it read all specific number from my mobile but when I use "body='Notifier'" , its not working , no display . Is there any solution to use those following code I provided? @RafsanJany

Comment: Can you  get all the messages without no filtering ??

Comment: I've tried, but I could not get all messages no one appear ,Im having trouble with this module, can you help me please? I appreciate any possible example @RafsanJany

Comment: @RafsanJany I've updated again my code above and I also get all the messages if my message is equal to "Notifier" it works, but the problem is how I can display the message if my message is like "Notifier with message" it only works on "Notifier" specific word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get each message as a String then simple **contains** filter should works.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String strbody = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("body") );
        if(strbody.contains("Notifier")){
             System.out.println ( strbody );
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strbody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```